# How to avoid non reachable code with switch-case?

Tags: go

We have below code scenario:

```
func f(a, b, c *int) *int {

    check := c == nil
    switch check {
    case true:
        if g(a) {
            return nil
        }
        return h(a)
    case false:
        return k(a, b, c)
    }
    return nil // non reachable code
}
```

---

`return nil` is non-reachable code. Reproducible code: https://play.golang.org/p/lIrTxZkNbg6

Why Go compiler complains about non-reachable code? How to avoid non-reachable code? Is switch-case syntax causing non-reachable code?

Comment: Because that code is not reachable. Your switch already handles all posible values: `true` and `false`, and returns in all cases. There's no logical way to reach that line.

Comment: I don't see any complains on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lIrTxZkNbg6). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you wish to avoid it, then don't have your switch statement handle all cases.  The other option is just to delete the non-reachable line.

Comment: @Flimzy Goal is to delete non-reachable line. Deleting nonreachable line gives error

Comment: What error? It sounds like there's more going on than your code snippet lets on. Please update the question with a complete reproduction case.

Comment: @Flimzy `missing return at end of function` error. Here is the reproducible example..https://play.golang.org/p/lIrTxZkNbg6

Comment: What is producing the error? It's not the compiler, your "reproducible example" works fine.

Comment: @Flimzy Comment the non-reachable code, it gives error: `missing return at end of function`

Comment: Sounds like a linter run by your IDE.  So your options are: refactor your code, or silence the linter. Considering that a switch statement doesn't really make sense for a boolean, I'd suggest the refactoring route.

Comment: @Flimzy check this https://play.golang.org/p/vzyDprcNgC4

Comment: @overexchange check this https://play.golang.org/p/lIrTxZkNbg6 (Flimzy right, issue with IDE or linter, my bet on linter).

Answer (score 2):

rewrite your function in more simple terms (using `if`).

```
func f(a, b, c *int) *int {

        if c == nil {
            if g(a) {
                return nil
            }
            return h(a)
        }
        
        return k(a, b, c)
}
```

Comment: Agreed an if statement is better, but that doesn't really answer the original question.

Comment: original question have lack of understanding "why it uses switch", not why it has "non reachable end" or "missing return"

Comment: @OlegButuzov you are right, Wrong usage of switch

Answer (score 2):

Your switch statement is evaluating a boolean which has just 2 possible choices, so there is no possibility for it to ever reach the final return statement.
In this specific case it is more readable to use `if` instead of switch

```
if check {
    if g(a) {
        return nil
    }
    return h(a)
}
return k(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler only knows that the statement is unreachable if it follows a [terminating statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Terminating_statements). Terminating switch statements are:

> A "switch" statement in which:
>
> - there are no "break" statements referring to the "switch" statement,
> - there is a default case, and
> - the statement lists in each case, including the default, end in a terminating statement, or a possibly labeled "fallthrough" statement.

So, the rules aren't comprehensive enough to determine this case where *every possible value of the switched data type has a terminating case* (as you have here). This rule would add needless complexity to the compiler and language as, practically, it would only apply to the exact situation you've shown here, which can (and should) easily be replaced by if/else statements.

Keep in mind that case values in a switch statement don't necessarily need to be constant or unique, and `bool` is arguably the only data type that has few enough unique values that you might realistically cover all of them in a switch statement.